# notify users when updating same record mysql php only

Tags: php, html, mysql

I know there are answers for this question already. but I was thinking if there is a way to notify users when they updated the same record from MySQL at the same time using only php codes.

I have a table for user logs. I think the first user activity (which is update the record) will be saved in the logs. then use that record to compare the time of the second user and if it is less than a few seconds, it will be notified to redo the update. Does it make sense?

```
 $sql="SELECT logdate FROM manage WHERE log_id=(SELECT MAX(log_id) FROM manage)";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
   $rows = $row[0];
   echo $rows;
   $sql="select timestampdiff(SECOND,now(),'$rows')";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
   $s = $row[0];
   echo " ".$s." ";   
   if ($s<=1 and $s>=0) {
       echo "redo update";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment on the question, but why not just remove capabilities to even insert into database if a recent user has already done an insert?

Steps:

1. Check if id has been inserted within a few seconds
2. If yes: not allow insert; if no: allow insert.

More explanation please if this doesn't relate to the question.

Comment: makes sense but my question is for updates. when 2 users modify the same record at the same time, either or both users will be notified that the record is modified recently.

Comment: I don't believe there is a native way of MySQL to do that. What you can attempt to do, if I got the request correctly, is: 


Person 1,2,3,4 writes at single time; Then you have a select query to get all the users and notify them.